# how to convert .rst files to .ipynb(.ipnb) and .py?

Tags: python, converters, jupyter-notebook, restructuredtext, docutils

There is a known way of converting .ipnb files to .rst with docutils, but could we convert .rst files in .ipnb, .py?

Please, provide an example, if possible.

Comment: do you mean `.ipynb`?

Comment: Yes, Paul H, shurely, .ipynb. Thanks, i've fixed my question.